# Javascript error: Unable to get property of 'click' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following item in my website which have master page;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" Runat="Server">
    <div class="div-data-upload">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="upldExcelTemplate" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrowse" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnBrowse" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Browse" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Enabled="False" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

where my FileUpload item is hidden. This is because I want to style the FileUpload control using CSS.

In order to call upldExcelTemplate (FileUpload control), i have used the following code but no success;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnBrowse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + upldExcelTemplate.ClientID + "').click(); return false;");
}

function fileBrowse(obj)
{
    document.getElementById(obj).click();
}

function fileBrowse()
{
    $('#upldExcelTemplate').click()
}
```

All this code end up with "Javascript error: Unable to get property of 'click' of undefined or null reference".

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: your ID's are not what you think they are - look at the source code in the browser and you'll see that

Comment: there are two function by same name

Comment: Seems that `Visible="false"` messing up since it probably means the control doesn't rendered on client-side and can't be accessed by JS. Try hiding the control in client-side using CSS class containing selector `"display: none;"`.

Comment: @brk there are no two function by the same name... what I show you is the example of code that I try to make this work... in which there are 3...

Comment: @Fahmieyz: @brk mentions `fileBrowse` function declared twice with same name in your question (I expect only one of them currently set). But most likely the problem comes from control visibility instead of client ID.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like been point out by Tetsuya Yamamoto, the Visible=false is the cause of the error...

so I put my FileUpload control into a div with display:none; as follow;

```
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="none">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="upldExcelTemplate" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrowse" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnBrowse" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Browse" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Enabled="False" />
</ContentTemplate>

.none {
    display: none
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnBrowse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + upldExcelTemplate.ClientID + "').click(); return false;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be getting a client id of the server control.

```
document.getElementById("<%=upldExcelTemplate.ClientID%>").click();
```

if you want it jquery

```
$(#"<%=upldExcelTemplate.ClientID%>").get()[0].click();
```

**upd:**

```
<button onclick="fileBrowse('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>')">click</button>
<script>
    function fileBrowse(obj) {
        document.getElementById(obj).click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can I edit the code so that i can used it as fileBrowse(obj)... i try to used document.getElementById(obj).click(); where obj = "<%=upldExcelTemplate.ClientID%>" but it seem my server tag is wrong